# Identify python errors

Tags: python, compiler-errors

Can someone assist with identifying the errors in this loop?

I am completely new to Python.

```
for p in players:
    x = len(p)
    dice = random.randint(0, x*2)
    print p + " rolls a " + dice + " out of " + str(x*2)
    if dice > x: 
       print p + " wins!"
    elif dice == x:
           print p + "gets a tie."
    else:
           print p + " loses."}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What errors did it raise? Why do you have a `}` at the end of your last line? Why is `x` capital in your if statement?

Comment: Error raised was line 1 NameError: players not defined. X is capitalized in exercise (this is one of those learning exercises. That '}' at the end was my error.

Comment: you haven't defined what is players??? what is actually players?? is it a list of random numbers??

Comment: Did you defined `players` beforehand ? You should take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes sorry players was identified as; players =['Tom', 'Jane']

Comment: How do i close this request and mark as answered?

Comment: @OldSpartan: marking an answer as accepted is part of the [tour] - also have a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works in Python 3.x

```
import random

players = ["Player 1", "Player 2"]

for p in players:
    x = len(p)
    dice = random.randint(0, x*2)
    print(str(p) + " rolls a " + str(dice) + " out of " + str(x*2))
    if dice > x:
        print(p + " wins!")
    elif dice == x:
        print(p + "gets a tie.")
    else:
        print(p + " loses.")
```

For Python 2.x

```
import random

players = ["Player 1", "Player 2"]

for p in players:
    x = len(p)
    dice = random.randint(0, x*2)
    print(str(p) + " rolls a " + str(dice) + " out of " + str(x*2))
    if dice > x:
        print p + " wins!"
    elif dice == x:
        print p + "gets a tie." 
    else:
        print p + " loses."
```

or add `from __future__ import print_function` to first example to ensure compability between Python 3 and 2.

Comment: Thank you anatol; gives me a lot to reference against. Much appreciated